Как в SQL таблице `upgrades` удалить все элементы, у которых `first_item_id` не уникальный?
Задача придельно простая, но решение не однозначное, спросил у нейросети, несколько раз и у каждого запроса было разное количество затронутых строк

Задача придельно простая Это ты фигню сказал. Озвученная задача очень сильно недоопределена.  Если, к примеру, СУБД - MySQL, имеются абсолютные дубликаты строк (нет первичного ключа), и надо оставить одну запись из дубликатов, то задача вот ни разу не тривиальная, и с ней придётся сильно покорячиться.

Обычно используется что-то типа такого, если правильно помню:
delete from upgrades as t1 
where exists(
    select * from upgrades as t2 
    where t1.first_item_id=t2.first_item_id
      and t1.id>t2.id)

Это на случай, если нужно удалить не все такие элементы и оставить один из них (самый первый по id).
А если прямо все такие удалить, то что-то типа:
delete from upgrades
where first_item_id in 
   (select first_item_id from upgrades
    group by first_item_id
    having count(*)>1)


используется что-то типа такого Не, просто DELETE t1 FROM t AS t1 JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.column=t2.column WHERE t1.id>t2.id

@Akina Никак не привыкну, что в DELETE можно FROM ... JOIN писать )  Да, так проще.
